# Animation Node 2.0 Object Instancer question

Tags: modifiers, node-editor, animation-nodes

we're trying to understand how Animation Node 2.0 work.
We usually use Cinema 4d and mograph, but we would like to try blender.

I've noticed that object instancer accept only a single object, and i cannot use a group as input, neither a object list or something else.

parenting object doesn't help too.

Join is not considered, because let's say that we want to animate all sphere with their center, and keep al as parametric as possible.

I'm sure i'm doing some mistake.

Someone can help us please?

Thanks in advance.

Max.

[image]

Comment: There is no way to instance multiple objects at the same time. But of course there is a way to do what you want, would you like me to write an answer about that?

Comment: Hi Omar, thanks for reply. Well i suppose that using same node with other objects will work, or something like this.
But may be this will be a bit long and tediuos if we got a lot of object. I assume we can also use group imported as link to have just a single object. 
Will be more easy maybe with Sverchok ?

Or if you have a fast alternative and you can show to us will be nice.
Thanks a lot.
Max.

Answer (score 1):

Animation Nodes is a powerful system, but it is bare bones in certain aspects. The best way to make something like your scene is by using procedural methods.

Lets say you have `m` number of polygons, you want `n` number of spheres to be sticking out of each face, then you should instance a sphere `m*n` number of times. To position the spheres we will need the polygons centers and normals. We will repeat the list of the centers and normals `n` number of times to match the number of spheres. All we have to do is to set the location of the sphere to the the center plus the normal multiplied by some factor, the problem is that there will be `n` number of sphere at each face. So to solve this, the factor will be constant for each layer of spheres but increases by each layer. From that reasoning, we can implement this like this (Let me know if you need a more detailed explanation):

[image: Node Tree]

This will result in:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you Omar! you gave us a lot material to work on. We will check your nodes and try something. THe real problem we will have is that we wish to replicate some parts of a spaceship. Those parts are parented and maybe will be animated too. So we need to use a group or parent tree. But this great example you made for us will help anyway to better understand AN. Thanks a lot !